# How to use route arguments in angular sub(-sub) components?

Tags: angular

In my app, I have two routes. Both of them render a component called "persona-details".

However, this component should now differ, depending on which route they are under. So in a way two "modes".

Since in both cases various child components (with partly further children) are used, these must know also at any time, in "which mode" to work.

How can I implement this with Angular?

```
"my-profile" (route)
    <my-profile> (routet component)
     |
     |___<persona-details> (rendered component; need to know is in mode 'my')
             |
             |___<some_child> (rendered component; need to know is in mode 'my')

"employee_profile" (route)
     <employee-profile> (routet component)
     |
     |___<persona-details> (rendered component; need to know is in mode 'employee')
             |
             |___<some_child> (rendered component; need to know is in mode 'employee')
             |___<some_child2> (rendered component; need to know is in mode 'employee')
```

**Please consider**: it is NOT about sub-routes!!! There are only two routes that have a component with the same name on the first level (route "`A`" ("`my-profile`") routes to "`A-Component`", route "`B`" ("`employee_profile`") routes to "`B-Component`") and these components render the same component (i.e. `persona-details`). `Persona-Details` then renders in the template depending on the diverese other components (let's say as an example "`change-password-btn`") which then also have to know like persona-details itself in which mode they are located / under which route ("`A`"/"`B`").

EDIT: Motivated by @Pieterjan 's comment, I further specified/edited the question. Both routes initially route to a different component, but each does nothing but render `<persona-details>`.

Comment: I would stick to using separate pages per route. You can always re-use a shared component on both pages. Problem with your approach is that navigating from one page straight to the other will not recreate your page, and you have to watch for `ActivatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe...` which overcomplicates stuff unnecessarily

Comment: Yes good point, of course I don't route "directly" to the same component, but to one with the same name (as the route is called). There nothing else is done so far than rendering the corresponding component.
I've edited the question!

Comment: You can use `ngTemplateOutlet` to show child component based on your route. Not sure more but it will help you to render your different templates as well. Share more details then we will discuss this more as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this normally, but I am not sure, if this work when router is used too.

```
export class PersonaDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Optional() myParent?: MyProfileComponent,
    @Optional() employeeParent?: EmployeeProfileComponent,
  ) { }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add resolvers to the routes and read the resolved value in the component.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'my-profile', resolve: { type: 'me' }, component: ... },
  { path: 'employee-profile', resolve: { type: 'employee' }, component: ... },
];

export class PersonaDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    route.snapshot.data.type // 'me' | 'employee'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'persona-details', component: PersonalComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'some_child', component: SomeChildComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

and then in ts

```
export class PersonaDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  mode: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.mode = params.get('mode');
    });
  }
}
```

and in html

```
<div *ngIf="mode === 'employee'">
  <!--what/ever-->
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help me at all. The point is that the components should "know" under which route they are located in order to make case distinctions.

Comment: use a string variable and ngif

Comment: as said, it's not about sub-routes, but components that were rendered by the same compoent (in the template)